# Create an if-elif scenario statement as a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following statement, `if col1="string1" and col2="string3"` then `newcol="newstring"` and if `col1="stringX"` and `col2="stringY"` then `newcol="newstringZ"`, how do I frame this into a dictionary so that I can apply map function to use the dictionary to check and insert new column for a dataframe?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
        'col1': ['string1', 'string1', 'string3', 'stringX', 
                '','stringX'],
        'col2': ["stringY","string3","stringY",np.nan,"stringY","stringY"]
}
)
```

After applying map function, the end result should look like this

[image]

Comment: `newcol = mapping[col1][col2]` ?

Comment: You can set up your conditions and use `np.select`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to put codes into a dictionary and apply map function for the codes. The nearest you can do is to put the data (instead of codes) that corresponding to the testing columns into the dictionary and apply map function to these data.

You can set the dict with tuples of (`col1`, `col2`) as keys and values for `newcol` as values.  Then, turn `col1`, `col2` as a tuple (composite key) by [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on `axis=1`.  Then use [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function for the mapping, as follows:

```
mapper = {('string1', 'string3') : 'newstring', 
          ('stringX', 'stringY') : 'newstringZ'}

df['newcol'] = df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(tuple, axis=1).map(mapper)
```

Note: every key in the dict is a 2-tuple, so use `('StringX', np.nan)` for the (`col1`, `col2`) composite key for row index 3 in the sample data above and use `('', 'StringY')` for row index 4.

**Result:**

```
print(df)


      col1     col2      newcol
0  string1  stringY         NaN
1  string1  string3   newstring
2  string3  stringY         NaN
3  stringX      NaN         NaN
4           stringY         NaN
5  stringX  stringY  newstringZ
```

Comment: It doesn't work when I try with the  `mapper = {('string1', 'string3') : 'newstring', 
                                                                            ('stringX') : 'newstringZ'}`

Comment: @Fazli  Every key has to be a tuple of 2 entries.  Use `('StringX', np.nan)` for the second key instead.

Comment: @Fazli  Any further question or help required ?  Feel free to let me know the latest status how's the problem now, solved or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's use 'merge' with a dataframe constructor:

```
dict_map = {'col1':['string1','stringX'], 'col2':['string3', 'stringY'], 'newcol':['newstring', 'newstringZ']}

df_map = pd.DataFrame(dict_map)

df.merge(df_map, how='left')
```

Output:

```
      col1     col2      newcol
0  string1  stringY         NaN
1  string1  string3   newstring
2  string3  stringY         NaN
3  stringX      NaN         NaN
4           stringY         NaN
5  stringX  stringY  newstringZ
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
df['newcol'] = np.select([df['col1'].eq('string1') & df['col2'].eq('string3'),
                          df['col1'].eq('stringX') & df['col2'].eq('stringY')],
                          choicelist=['newstring', 'newstringZ'], default='')
```

Output result:

```
>>> df
      col1     col2      newcol
0  string1  stringY            
1  string1  string3   newstring
2  string3  stringY            
3  stringX      NaN            
4           stringY            
5  stringX  stringY  newstringZ
```